# MS Forms restrict multiple choice to a defined number

Tags: sharepoint-online, form, ms-flow

is there a way to restrict the multiple choice feature of MS forms? Let's say I have 60 option but users are only allowed to choose 10. When they reached the 10th, the form should block their choices.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean spfx custom form or list form?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Forms is currently unable to do this, you can submit your request in the Microsoft Forms feedback community:

https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/0ab9de26-ff1b-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472